# Socket event handler access to socket instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to make my application more modular by moving socket event handlers to different files. specifically, i'm trying to do this

```
socket.on('foo',fooHandler)
socket.on('bar',barHandler)
```

however , the handlers dont seem to have access to the socket instance. this doesnt work

```
fooHandler = (data) => {
  console.log(socket.id)
}
```

socket is undefined. Is there a way i can access socket instance within the function. i've tried `this.socket.id` or specifying the `socket` argument in my handler. they dont seem to work

Comment: Could you please show the code.

Comment: Try just using `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because i was using es6. works now if i use es5

```
const skill_suggestions = function(data,res){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind` function

```
socket.on('foo', fooHandler.bind(socket))
socket.on('bar', barHandler.bind(socket))

fooHandler = (data) {   
// NOTE: You CAN'T use arrow function: fooHandler = (data) => ... here 
// because it will ignore your `bind'
  console.log(this.id)  // `this' is socket
}
```

You can optimize:

```
socket.on2 = function (arg, func) {
    socket.on(arg, func.bind(socket))
}
// Then:
socket.on2('foo', fooHandler)
```